# React - When switching between profiles, the rendering conditions for the previous profile are displayed

Tags: reactjs, tabs, rendering

I create the React application, where I want to show several profiles.
On the profile page, I want to use tabs to show information about a profile: for example, name and number.
To switch between profiles, I added the prev and next button.

#### *And I have the following problem:*

If I switched profile tabs from "Name" to "Number", and after that I move on to the next profile, I see the next profile with the already active "Number" tab. But I expect to see the status of the profile with the default "Name".

And the same problem, if I sorted the information inside the profile tab, and then go to the next profile, I get the sorted information for the next profile already.

I can not understand where I was mistaken and will be very grateful for help.

```js
// my profiles.json
let profiles = [{"name":"John", "count": 2}, {"name":"Kitty", "count": 3}, {"name":"Ji", "count": 4}]

const ProfileName = (props) => (
    <div><h1>{props.name}</h1></div>
)

const ProfileCount = (props) => (
    <div><h1>{props.count}</h1></div>
)

const Prev = (props) => (
  <button onClick={props.toggle} disabled={props.active}>Prev</button>
)

const Next = (props) => (
  <button onClick={props.toggle} disabled={props.active}>Next</button>
)

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
  }

  handleTabClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onClick(this.props.tabIndex)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className='tab'>
        <a className={`tab-link ${this.props.linkClassName} 
      ${this.props.isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}
        onClick={this.handleTabClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.linkClassName}</a>
      </li>
    )
  }
}

class Tabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
      activeTabIndex: 0
    }
    this.handleTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleTabClick(tabIndex) {
    this.setState({
      activeTabIndex: tabIndex === this.state.activeTabIndex ?
      this.props.defaultActiveTabIndex : tabIndex
    })
  }

  renderChild() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        onClick: this.handleTabClick,
        tabIndex: index,
        isActive: index === this.state.activeTabIndex
      })
    })
  }

  renderContent() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { activeTabIndex } = this.state
    if (children[activeTabIndex]) {
      return children[activeTabIndex].props.children
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.renderChild()}
        </ul>
        <div className='tabcontent'>
          {this.renderContent()}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Tabs.defaultProps = {
  defaultActiveTabIndex: null
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      index: 1,
      disabledNext: false,
      disabledPrev: false
    }
  }

  togglePrev(e) {
    let index = this.state.index - 1;
    let disabledPrev = (index === 0);

    this.setState({ index: index, disabledPrev: disabledPrev, disabledNext: false })
  }

   toggleNext(e) {
     let index = this.state.index + 1;
     let disabledNext = index === (this.props.profiles.length - 1);

     this.setState({ index: index, disabledNext: disabledNext, disabledPrev: false })
   }
  render() {
   const { index, disabledNext, disabledPrev } = this.state
   const profile = this.props.profiles ? this.props.profiles[index] : null

   if (profile) {
     return (
       <div className='profile'>
          <Prev toggle={(e) => this.togglePrev(e)} active={disabledPrev} />
         <Next toggle={(e) => this.toggleNext(e)} active={disabledNext} />
          <Tabs>
            <Tab linkClassName={'Name'}><ProfileName {...profile} /></ Tab>
            <Tab linkClassName={'Number'}><ProfileCount {...profile} /></ Tab>
          </ Tabs>
       </div>
     )
   } else {
     return <span>error</span>
   }
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <div><Main profiles={profiles} /></div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #6161a7;
}

li.tab { display: inline-block }

a {
    color: white;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;   
}

a.active { background: #969696 }

.tabcontent {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It works fine for me, I think it's unclear of what you're asking.

Comment: If you for example in profile "Kitty" choose the tab "Number" and then click the button "next", you see number "3", but I want to see name of  profile as a default state

Comment: Or if you sort data for profile "Kitty" and then click the button "next", you see also sorted data for the next profile instead name of  profile and data without sorting as a default state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Main Component you have "defaultActiveTabIndex" property, but you are never propagating it to child (Tabs) component.

If you propagate it to Tabs component:

Main Component:

```
    render() {
    const {
      index,
      disabledNext,
      disabledPrev,
      defaultActiveTabIndex
    } = this.state;
    const profile = this.props.profiles ? this.props.profiles[index] : null;

    if (profile) {
      return (
        <div className="profile">
          <Prev toggle={e => this.togglePrev(e)} active={disabledPrev} />
          <Next toggle={e => this.toggleNext(e)} active={disabledNext} />
          <Tabs defaultActiveTabIndex={defaultActiveTabIndex}>
            <Tab linkClassName={"Name"}>
              <ProfileName {...profile} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab linkClassName={"Number"}>
              <ProfileCount {...profile} />
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <span>error</span>;
    }
}
```

You can use it when your component gets new props and reset current active tab to default active tab property:

Tabs Component:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    const { defaultActiveTabIndex } = props;
    if (defaultActiveTabIndex !== this.state.activeTabIndex) {
      this.setState({ activeTabIndex: defaultActiveTabIndex });
    }
  }
```

I also added defaultActiveTabIndex change inside of prev & next toggle methods (inside of MainComponent):

```
  togglePrev(e) {
    let index = this.state.index - 1;
    let disabledPrev = index === 0;

    this.setState({
      index: index,
      disabledPrev: disabledPrev,
      defaultActiveTabIndex: 0,
      disabledNext: false
    });
  }

  toggleNext(e) {
    let index = this.state.index + 1;
    let disabledNext = index === this.props.profiles.length - 1;

    this.setState({
      index: index,
      disabledNext: disabledNext,
      defaultActiveTabIndex: 0,
      disabledPrev: false
    });
  }
```

It is not inevitable in your case, but I've put it there, so you know you can change it there - in case you want to show different "default" active tab on prev/next press.

The full (working) code sample is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6x6mmr6vwk

Hope this helps!